# How to disable tracing through web.config file

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, trace

for enabling the tracing I wrote the below code both in web.config of webrole project and app.config of worker role project. and it is working also

```
<system.web>
<trace enabled="true" requestLimit="10" localOnly="false"
pageOutput="false" writeToDiagnosticsTrace="true"/>
</system.web>
<system.diagnostics>
    <trace autoflush="true">
        <listeners>
            <add type="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.DiagnosticMonitorTraceListener, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
                name="AzureDiagnostics">
                <filter type="" />
            </add>
        </listeners>
    </trace>
</system.diagnostics>
```

i have wrote the below code for disabling the tracing, but it is not working

```
  <system.web>
<trace enabled="false" requestLimit="10" localOnly="true"
pageOutput="false" writeToDiagnosticsTrace="false"/>
</system.web>
<system.diagnostics>
    <trace autoflush="false">
        <listeners>
            <add type="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.DiagnosticMonitorTraceListener, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
                name="AzureDiagnostics">
                <filter type="" />
            </add>
        </listeners>
    </trace>
</system.diagnostics>
```

Comment: looks like what you have should work (i.e. disable tracing).  Usually just setting enabled="false" does the trick.  Maybe your @Page directives have tracing enabled, or perhaps somewhere else?

Comment: If it is not working, Comment out <system.diagnostic> tag.

Comment: What Faizan said will work. Srujana is messagelogging enabled?

Answer (score -1):

When you want to disable Trace, use the following code.

```
Trace.IsEnabled=false;
```

Hope this works!

Jag